# ES6 promises, chaining promises only if previous promises were rejected, while keeping rejection reasons

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm building an authentication API that tries to authenticate against different authentication methods until one succeeds (like Spring Security).

Each authentication method returns a promise, fulfilled if the authentication did succeed, rejected if the authentication did fail.

To try to authenticate a user, I need call the authentication methods sequentially:

- If the first authentication method succeeds the user is authenticated and I
  don't want the other authentication methods to be called.
- If the first authentication method fails, I need to try the second authentication method. And so on...
- If none of the authentication methods succeed, I need to reject the authentication and maybe to
  know the reasons every authentication did fail.
- If an authentication succeeds I need to get back a value (authentication object).

This process is almost what promises libraries call **.any** (or **.some**) except that I don't want to execute every promises (hence try every authentication methods, which induces unnecessary workload). **I want to try the next authentication method only if the previous failed**.

Question 1: Is there a function available in a Promise/A+ compliant library that already does that ?
Question 2: I've been thinking of the following way (cf code below), is there any better way ?

```
// Defining some promise factories
var promiseFactory1 = {
    buildPromise: function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('trying p1...');
            // resolve('p1 success');
            reject('p1 failure');
        })
    }
};

var promiseFactory2 = {
    buildPromise: function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('trying p2...');
            // resolve('p2 success');
            reject('p2 failure');
        })
    }
};

var promiseFactory3 = {
    buildPromise: function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('trying p3...');
            resolve('p3 success');
            // reject('p3 failure');
        })
    }
};

// Building the promise
let promisesFactory = [promiseFactory1, promiseFactory2, promiseFactory3];
let rejections = [];

var reducedPromise = promisesFactory.reduce(function(promise, nextFactory) {
    if (promise === null) return nextFactory.buildPromise();

    return promise.catch(err => {
        rejections.push(err);
        return nextFactory.buildPromise();
    });
}, null);

reducedPromise
    .catch(err => {
        rejections.push(err); // catching the last rejection
    })
    .then(success => {
        if(rejections.length == promisesFactory.length) {
            console.log(rejections);
            // TODO return Promise.reject(new SomeCustomError());
        } else {
            console.log(success);
            // TODO return Promise.resolve(success);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do it like this (where `auth1`, `auth2`, and `auth3` are the auth functions returning promises):

```
auth1(/*args*/)
    .catch(failed => auth2(/*args*/))
    .catch(failed => auth3(/*args*/))
    .then(result => {
      console.log("Success:" + result);
      return result;
    })
    .catch(failed => {
      console.log("Failure:" + failed);
    });
```

Because we don't have `then` callbacks, the resolution value propagates to the final `then` (just like having `.then(result => result)`); but we return new promises from the `catch` callbacks, triggering the next authentication method.

The `then` at the end gets the resolution value of the first succeeding auth method; the final `catch` above just gets the rejection reason of the *last* failing auth method (`auth3`).

[Live on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=test(false%2C%20false%2C%20false)%0A%20%20.then(()%20%3D%3E%20test(true%2C%20false%2C%20false))%0A%20%20.then(()%20%3D%3E%20test(false%2C%20true%2C%20false))%0A%20%20.then(()%20%3D%3E%20test(false%2C%20false%2C%20true))%3B%0Afunction%20test(a1%2C%20a2%2C%20a3)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22Testing%20%22%20%2B%20%5Ba1%2C%20a2%2C%20a3%5D.join(%22%2C%20%22))%3B%0A%20%20return%20auth1(a1)%0A%20%20%20%20.catch(failed%20%3D%3E%20auth2(a2))%0A%20%20%20%20.catch(failed%20%3D%3E%20auth3(a3))%0A%20%20%20%20.then(result%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Success%3A%20%22%20%2B%20result)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20.catch(failed%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Failed%3A%20%22%20%2B%20failed)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20auth1(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22a1%20good%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reject(%22a1%20bad%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0Afunction%20auth2(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22a2%20good%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reject(%22a2%20bad%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0Afunction%20auth3(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22a3%20good%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reject(%22a3%20bad%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0A)

If you need all the failing reasons, you could keep them in an array:

```
let failures = [];
auth1(/*args*/)
    .catch(failed => {failures.push(failed); return auth2(/*args*/);})
    .catch(failed => {failures.push(failed); return auth3(/*args*/);})
    .then(result => {
      console.log("Success: " + result + " (failed: " + failures.join(", ") + ")");
      return result;
    })
    .catch(failed => {
      failures.push(failed);
      console.log("Failures: " + failures.join(", "));
    });
```

[Live Copy](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=test(false%2C%20false%2C%20false)%0A%20%20.then(()%20%3D%3E%20test(true%2C%20false%2C%20false))%0A%20%20.then(()%20%3D%3E%20test(false%2C%20true%2C%20false))%0A%20%20.then(()%20%3D%3E%20test(false%2C%20false%2C%20true))%3B%0Afunction%20test(a1%2C%20a2%2C%20a3)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22Testing%20%22%20%2B%20%5Ba1%2C%20a2%2C%20a3%5D.join(%22%2C%20%22))%3B%0A%20%20let%20failures%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20return%20auth1(a1)%0A%20%20%20%20.catch(failed%20%3D%3E%20%7Bfailures.push(failed)%3B%20return%20auth2(a2)%3B%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20.catch(failed%20%3D%3E%20%7Bfailures.push(failed)%3B%20return%20auth3(a3)%3B%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20.then(result%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Success%3A%20%22%20%2B%20result%20%2B%20%22%20(failed%3A%20%22%20%2B%20failures.join(%22%2C%20%22)%20%2B%20%22)%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20.catch(failed%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20failures.push(failed)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Failures%3A%20%22%20%2B%20failures.join(%22%2C%20%22))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20auth1(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22a1%20good%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reject(%22a1%20bad%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0Afunction%20auth2(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22a2%20good%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reject(%22a2%20bad%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0Afunction%20auth3(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22a3%20good%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reject(%22a3%20bad%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0A)

If your auth methods are themselves in an array, you can do the above in a loop:

```
let auths = [auth1.bind(null, /*args*/), auth2.bind(null, /*args*/), auth3.bind(null, /*args*/)];
return auths.reduce((p, auth) => p.catch(failed => auth()), Promise.reject())
    .then(result => {
      console.log("Success: " + result);
      return result;
    })
    .catch(failed => {
      console.log("Failed: " + failed);
    });
```

[Live Copy](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=test(false%2C%20false%2C%20false)%0A%20%20.then(()%20%3D%3E%20test(true%2C%20false%2C%20false))%0A%20%20.then(()%20%3D%3E%20test(false%2C%20true%2C%20false))%0A%20%20.then(()%20%3D%3E%20test(false%2C%20false%2C%20true))%3B%0Afunction%20test(a1%2C%20a2%2C%20a3)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22Testing%20%22%20%2B%20%5Ba1%2C%20a2%2C%20a3%5D.join(%22%2C%20%22))%3B%0A%20%20let%20auths%20%3D%20%5Bauth1.bind(null%2C%20a1)%2C%20auth2.bind(null%2C%20a2)%2C%20auth3.bind(null%2C%20a3)%5D%3B%0A%20%20return%20auths.reduce((p%2C%20auth)%20%3D%3E%20p.catch(failed%20%3D%3E%20auth())%2C%20Promise.reject())%0A%20%20%20%20.then(result%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Success%3A%20%22%20%2B%20result)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20.catch(failed%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Failed%3A%20%22%20%2B%20failed)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20auth1(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22a1%20good%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reject(%22a1%20bad%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0Afunction%20auth2(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22a2%20good%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reject(%22a2%20bad%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0Afunction%20auth3(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(succeed)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22a3%20good%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reject(%22a3%20bad%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: Hi T.J. thank you for the answer. Interesting use of bind null, but in my case it won't work because the authentication methods are in fact called on authentication providers objects and need this to be bound to the authentication provider object. I've also thought about using Promise.reject but while pushing into the failures array, I would insert a first 'artificial' failure I'll have to deal with afterwards, hence I've decided to start with a null promise. But this confirms that I was on the right path, thank you !

Comment: I don't know if a more elegant (readable) solution can be found using generators (I'm not yet 100% at ease combining generators and promises right now) ?

Comment: And do you know if any existing promise library already implements something like in my version or your 3rd combined to your 2nd (with the promise array and the failures array) ?

Comment: @thomas.g: The `this` thing shouldn't be a problem, just use the object instead of `null` in the `bind`. No, I don't know of a lib that would make it simpler. I don't think it's actually all that complicated above. :-)